# Constraints and Size Classes in Xcode 8 Beta

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, interface-builder

I'm trying to create landscape constraints in my app that differ from my portrait constraints. Usually I use size classes in previous versions of Xcode but I am using the beta and all I see are devices.

How do you use this new UI for size classes in Xcode 8? I don't see any documentation about this anywhere.

Cheers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Size classes work very similar to the way they used to.  The reason that you now see the devices are because there are so many different traits your device can adapt that change the way the UI works.  Not just landscape + portrait, but you have traits for any UI difference possible.  This includes things like Interface Style, Dynamic Type, and even the display Gamut.

This WWDC 2016 video will explain it all, and it will give a nice walkthrough of how to design for these new traits in xCode 8.

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/222/

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Great video however thats for making adaptive layouts in iPads. Problem with xcode 8 is it classes all iPhones in portrait as wC hR. Which is preventing from making adaptive layouts on the different iPhone screens. Any help there would be excellent.